# How to get roadlink data from link id using HERE API

Tags: rest, here-api

Given a LinkId I want to retrieve the corresponding road link data using HERE REST API.

I've used the routing API to get the road link id for a coordinate (the closest road link is return, which is what I want), but since it's a routing API it only returns the closest point on that road link, not the actual road link itself. I need the entire road link geometry, and I'd like to not have to specify tiles and map specific data.

API Get request: `https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&routeAttributes=shape,incidents&departure=now&legAttributes=all&app_id={APP ID}&app_code={APP CODE}&waypoint0=57.69935469580243,11.987510919570923&waypoint1=57.69935469580243,11.987510919570923&linkAttributes=all&jsonAttributes=128&maneuverAttributes=all`

Which yields:

```
{
    "MetaInfo": {
        ...
    },
    "Route": [
        {
            "Waypoint": [
                {
                    "LinkId": "+833889589",
                    "MappedPosition": {
                        "Latitude": 57.6992619,
                        "Longitude": 11.9864917
                    },
                    "OriginalPosition": {
                        "Latitude": 57.6993547,
                        "Longitude": 11.9875109
                    },
                    ...
                },
                {
                    "LinkId": "+833889589",
                    "MappedPosition": {
                        "Latitude": 57.6992619,
                        "Longitude": 11.9864917
                    },
                    "OriginalPosition": {
                        "Latitude": 57.6993547,
                        "Longitude": 11.9875109
                    },
                    ...
                }
            ],
            "Mode": {
                ...
            },
            "Shape": [
                "57.6992619,11.9864917",
                "57.6992619,11.9864917"
            ],
            "Leg": [
                {
                    "Start": {
                        "LinkId": "+833889589",
                        "MappedPosition": {
                            "Latitude": 57.6992619,
                            "Longitude": 11.9864917
                        },
                        "OriginalPosition": {
                            "Latitude": 57.6993547,
                            "Longitude": 11.9875109
                        },
                        ...
                    "End": {
                        "LinkId": "+833889589",
                        "MappedPosition": {
                            "Latitude": 57.6992619,
                            "Longitude": 11.9864917
                        },
                        "OriginalPosition": {
                            "Latitude": 57.6993547,
                            "Longitude": 11.9875109
                        },
                   ...
                    "Maneuver": [
                        {
                            "Position": {
                                "Latitude": 57.6992619,
                                "Longitude": 11.9864917
                            },
                            ....
                            "Shape": [
                                "57.6992619,11.9864917",
                                "57.6992619,11.9864917"
                            ],
                            ....
                        },
                        {
                            "Position": {
                                "Latitude": 57.6992619,
                                "Longitude": 11.9864917
                            },
                            ....
                        }
                    ],
                    "Link": [
                        {
                            "LinkId": "+833889589",
                            "Shape": [
                                "57.6992619,11.9864917",
                                "57.6992619,11.9864917"
                            ],
                            ....
                    },
                    "Shape": [
                        "57.6992619,11.9864917",
                        "57.6992619,11.9864917"
                    ],
                    ....
}
```

As you can see, the result contains a LinkId (good), but only a single point on that link (bad). I've looked around, specifically at the traffic flow API, and the Platform Data Extension API as suggested [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/introduction.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry information you need about link IDs can be retrieved from the Fleet telematics advanced data sets. The LINK_FC1...5 layers of the HERE map data will give you link connectivity/geometry information for all link IDs in a given map region. For example, given a road link ID, you can get the `REF_NODE_NEIGHBOR_LINKS` and the `NONREF_NODE_NEIGHBOR_LINKS` defined as follows:

`"REF_NODE_NEIGHBOR_LINKS": "Comma seperated list of LINK_IDs that are connected to this link via the reference node. If a LINK_ID is negative ('-') then this link is connected via it's non reference node.",
 "NONREF_NODE_NEIGHBOR_LINKS": "Comma seperated list of LINK_IDs that are connected to this link via the non reference node. If a LINK_ID is negative ('-') then this link is connected via it's non reference node."`

Please read through the documentation at https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/request-constructing.html.